# What is the equivalent of np.std() in TensorFlow?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Just looking for the equivalent of np.std() in TensorFlow to calculate the standard deviation of a tensor.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To get the mean and variance just use `tf.nn.moments`.

```
mean, var = tf.nn.moments(x, axes=[1])
```

For more on `tf.nn.moments` params see [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/moments)

Comment: How can I achieve this in c++ API?

Comment: I only see documentation for the mean in c++ API: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/cc/class/tensorflow/ops/mean I think you'd have to compute the variance yourself. sum[(x- u)^2]   You might be able to dig through the python source code for how they call the back end to see how to compute the variance more efficiently.

Comment: Notice: this calculates mean and "variance", not "std".

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `reduce_std` in the following code adapted from Keras:

```
#coding=utf-8
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def reduce_var(x, axis=None, keepdims=False):
    """Variance of a tensor, alongside the specified axis.

    # Arguments
        x: A tensor or variable.
        axis: An integer, the axis to compute the variance.
        keepdims: A boolean, whether to keep the dimensions or not.
            If `keepdims` is `False`, the rank of the tensor is reduced
            by 1. If `keepdims` is `True`,
            the reduced dimension is retained with length 1.

    # Returns
        A tensor with the variance of elements of `x`.
    """
    m = tf.reduce_mean(x, axis=axis, keep_dims=True)
    devs_squared = tf.square(x - m)
    return tf.reduce_mean(devs_squared, axis=axis, keep_dims=keepdims)

def reduce_std(x, axis=None, keepdims=False):
    """Standard deviation of a tensor, alongside the specified axis.

    # Arguments
        x: A tensor or variable.
        axis: An integer, the axis to compute the standard deviation.
        keepdims: A boolean, whether to keep the dimensions or not.
            If `keepdims` is `False`, the rank of the tensor is reduced
            by 1. If `keepdims` is `True`,
            the reduced dimension is retained with length 1.

    # Returns
        A tensor with the standard deviation of elements of `x`.
    """
    return tf.sqrt(reduce_var(x, axis=axis, keepdims=keepdims))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x_np = np.arange(10).reshape(2, 5).astype(np.float32)
    x_tf = tf.constant(x_np)
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        print(sess.run(reduce_std(x_tf, keepdims=True)))
        print(sess.run(reduce_std(x_tf, axis=0, keepdims=True)))
        print(sess.run(reduce_std(x_tf, axis=1, keepdims=True)))
    print(np.std(x_np, keepdims=True))
    print(np.std(x_np, axis=0, keepdims=True))
    print(np.std(x_np, axis=1, keepdims=True))
```

Comment: I'm using tf1.4, tf.nn.moments does not give me a correct result for some reason ... I tried your version and it worked on the first try :) +1

Comment: If I want to use this as a loss function, would it require keepdims set to True?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use directly:

```
tf.math.reduce_std(
    input_tensor, axis=None, keepdims=False, name=None
)
```

[Docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/reduce_std)